# SpriteKit background added outside of scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to position the background all over the scene background, but for some reason it puts it outside of screen.

This is what I used:

```
SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [self.atlas textureNamed:@"back"];
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture size:self.view.frame.size];
background.position = (CGPoint) {CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)};
[self addChild:background];
```

This is how it puts it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your background image to the SKScene view and as such determine the coordinates from self.

```
SKSpriteNode *backgroundNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"BackgroundImage"];
backgroundNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
backgroundNode.zPosition = 1;
[self addChild:backgroundNode];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was that in the new Xcode 6.3.1 when you create a new scene it adds a SKScene view of some kind, this view is bigger then the iPhone normal screen, maybe it's iPhone 6+ screen size that's why the background image was out of screen bounds. I just had to remove this view file and not reload it from code and then it worked out.

Thanks anyway, the comment above helped me to understand that.